# Ito integral of average of the square of a Wiener signal?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, random-walk, stochastic-analysis

How do we evaluate the average of the square of a Wiener signal?

**Standard case:**

Typically, the signal average is $S(t)=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}s(t)dt$, where we can write the integral in Ito form $S(t)=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dS$, where $dS=s(t)dt=\mu dt+\sigma dW$.

This is easy to evaluate
$$ S(t)=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dS=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}\left(\mu dt+\sigma dW\right)=\mu+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{T}}W_{\sigma^{2}=1}$$

**Squared case:**

We want to evaluate $$ S_2(t)=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}s(t)^2 dt $$

I guess the challenge is to write this in proper Ito form. It isn't obvious to me how to use Ito lemma here, since $S_{2}\neq S^{2}$ or some function $f(S)$. Is $S_2$ not an Ito process anymore?

**Naive approach:**

From the standard case, $s(t) = \frac{dS}{dt}=\mu+\sigma\xi(t)$, where $\xi (t)=\frac{dW}{dt}$.
So  $s(t)^2 = (\frac{dS}{dt})^2=\mu^2+\sigma^2\xi(t)^2+2 \mu\sigma\xi(t)$.

Integrating $\int_{0}^{T}s(t)^2 dt = \int_{0}^{T} (\frac{dS}{dt})^2 dt=\int_{0}^{T} \frac{dS}{dt}dS $, which I have no idea how to evaluate, or weather this is the right approach.

Comment: Further thought, $S_2$ can't ever be negative, so it is not a simple Winier process for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Without an additional regularisation (say with colored noise), the integral you are trying to compute is strongly divergent.

The integrand is dominated by $\xi^2=\left(\frac{dW}{dt}\right)^2$ which is positive and of order $\frac{1}{dt}$ and there is thus no hope to give it a meaning in the stochastic integral sense. You are just integrating infinite positive terms. Sometimes you may indeed see integrals of white noise squared exponentiated, e.g. :
$$ e^{-\int_0^T \xi(t)^2 dt + \cdots} $$
which are a physicist way of writing the Wiener measure in path integrals. However, they make no sense in the Ito formalism.